# Can I prioritise one UDP stream over another in linux?

Tags: linux, networking, python, qos, gstreamer

I made a small program in *python* that produces two *UDP* streams through *Gstreamer* framework. 
One is the main stream, labeled A, that MUST go through on port *3333*. The other one is a secondary stream, labeled B, that it's not mandatory to go through on port *5555*.
Because my network has a certain limit I would like to know if it would be possible to prioritize stream A over B so it uses the maximum bandwidth available, and then if there is space left for stream B, to send its packages.

Comment: Are you trying to limit these on local network traffic or internet traffic?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart preferably over internet but local network is still good as i can use a raspberry pi as a mediator

Comment: What's the make and model of your router? This type of prioritizing is accomplished by using quality of service at the router level.

Comment: I would prefer more of a software solution to this rather than add another router, do you think this would be possible?

Comment: It might be? But most routers these days have the service built into them. In most cases you just need to configure it.

Comment: I'm a networking guy though, I know this works on the router level (internet traffic). It can work on the local network level via vlans also. Maybe someone knows how to do this with the host routing table in Linux?

Comment: So it is in fact possible,at least from a internet traffic point of view, to be able to send almost 100% of stream A and then whats left from the available bandwidth send the B stream?

Comment: Yep, quality of service.

Comment: It's looks like you can do this by interface in Linux. I.e at the programs host machine. Which I was unaware of,http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/#i-assumptions